# Lexical scope trickiness Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

Can someone explain this curious behavior in JavaScript:

```
var x = 1;
function f (y) {return x + y;}
console.log(f(5));  // prints 6
x = 2;
console.log(f(5));  // prints 7
```

Based on lexical scoping and closures, I would expect to print `6` each time, since the `x` in `f` is cached as equal to `1`, correct?

Comment: The `f` function captures a reference to `x`. It doesn't capture its current value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Then why does [this work](http://jsbin.com/qukafawo/1/edit?js,console)? 

Is it because `childFunction()` serves as a closure that sorts the binding of `local` to `variable`? Whereas in the previous example, there was no closure created when the function `f` was defined?

Mostly I'm getting confused because I learned on ML, and JS acts differently.

Comment: Each function defines a variable scope. A variable scope has an implicit link to its outer function scope, which has a link to its outer scope... until you get to the global scope. So when a function references a variable, it looks for it in its own scope. If it can't find it, it looks for it in its immediate outer scope, and continues the search until the global scope, where if it can't find it there, it throws a ReferenceError. As such, a variable in a given scope will "shadow" a variable with the same name in an outer scope. So `var variable = "local"` shadows `var variable = "top-level"`.

Comment: ...The key thing about closures is that the function *keeps* that link to the outer scope that was created where the function was defined. So even if you pass the function into a different scope, the variable scope chain doesn't change. It behaves as though it was invoked where it was born.

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right... The second example works because the closure retains a link to the `var variable = "local"` binding. If that binding were not there, when the function is invoked it would find the binding of `var variable = "top-level"`, because when the closure was created and it tried to link something to `variable`, it found the binding in the global scope. Is that right(ish)?

Comment: Pretty much. Though I tend to think of it as a binding to the entire variable environment rather than to a single variable. The lexical environments are linked together upon creation (function invocation), and hold that link for their lifetime. So your innermost function could actually define which outer variable it wants to read in a dynamic/random way using `eval()`, and it'll always find it if the variable exists in some enclosing scope. That said... modern JS engines usually optimize to release variables that are not referenced by closures. Using `eval()` disables such optimizations.

Comment: ...[here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/qukafawo/3/edit) that uses `eval` to dynamically determine which variable to access. With no explicit references to outer variables from the innermost function, it still can read the outer variables because it links to the entire environment.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for the thorough explanation, and for providing the demo. So `eval()` allows you to access the value stored in each variable. This is handy if you want the name of your variable to itself be stored in a variable. Handy! You did an excellent job explaining. Gold star for you. :)

Comment: Well... let's back up a little. What `eval()` does is execute whatever string you provide as part of the program. I just used it to demonstrate that the individual variables aren't necessarily linked, but rather the entire variable environments. But `eval()` can be a serious security risk and performance hindrance and should *almost never* be used in real world code. If you ever want to access data by string value, then use objects instead. `var dynamic_name = "foo"; var data_obj = {foo: "my foo value", bar: "my bar value"}; console.log(data_obj[dynamic_name]);`

Comment: Ah, right, I remember reading that `eval()` poses a security risk. Thanks for clarifying, and showing how to do it more safely.